# Opening and reading a heapdump file not working on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, dump, heap-dump

To analyze very high CPU usage, we need to open the heapdump files sent to us on IntelliJ. IntelliJ claims "Rendering Flame Graph Data", but nothing happens effectively.

Note: This issue is not about creating the file. We already have the necessary .dmp file, now we just need to analyze it.

Does someone have an idea as to why nothing happens? How can we view the .dmp file?

Kindly bear with me, I'm still learning. Very grateful for any helpful hints!

Additionally to IntelliJ, we also tried opening the file with a text editor. Result: .dmp file not readable.

Additionally, our IT is blocking the Windows Store, which is why we can't download WinDbg.

Current state: .dmp not openable, not readable.
Runtime version: 11.0.13+7-b1751.25 amd64

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share the IDE logs via `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data` + a .dmp file. Files can be uploaded at https://uploads.jetbrains.com

Comment: Thank you Egor :) This is valuable input.